# How to skip rows from getting selected in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

How to skip rows from getting selected which are holding locks ?

```
Begin tran

Select * 
From table with(holdlock) 
Where id = 2
```

In second session, when query gets executed, the row which is has id value of 2 should be skipped in the result.

Comment: This smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I suggest you research the terms "optimistic concurrency" and "pessimistic concurrency", spend some time understanding how locking works generally, and then decide what your actual goal is and how to best implement it. There are discussions you can find if you are attempting to use a table as a queue.

Answer (score 2):

The `(holdlock)` holds the lock until the end of the transaction - but this is a **shared lock** - e.g. other readers **aren't blocked** by that lock ...

If you really must do this, you need to establish (and hold on to) an exclusive lock

```
Begin tran

Select * 
From table with (updlock, holdlock) 
Where id = 2
```

and use the `WITH (READPAST)` clause in the second session, not to be stopped by the exclusive lock.

PS: updated to use `updlock`, based on @charlieface's recommendation - thanks!

Comment: `UPDLOCK` is probably a better idea than `XLOCK`, it means that readers can still read, but another `UPDLOCK` is blocked

Comment: Thanks for the response , but this trick is not working. as the in second session all data are still loading in result with readpast hint.

Answer (score 1):

`READPAST` will skip existing locks. **But you need another lock hint, otherwise `SELECT` will not keep the lock.**

`XLOCK, HOLDLOCK` (aka `SERIALIZABLE`) is an option, but can be restrictive.

You can use `UPDLOCK` to keep a lock until the end of the transaction. `UPDLOCK` generates a `U` lock, which blocks other `U` or `X` (exclusive writer) locks, but still allows `S` reader locks. So the data can still be read by a read-only process, but another process executing this same code would still be blocked.

```sql
Begin tran

Select * 
From table WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST) 
Where id = 2

-- etc
```

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this with following code in second session.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READS
Select * from table WITH (Readpast)
```

Thank you all for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can try READPAST-hint

https://www.sqlshack.com/explore-the-sql-query-table-hint-readpast/

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but readpast hint works when there is insert / update / delete activity going on , here there is only select process. Also I tried this but not working.